# How to see if more than one of the same values is used in a row inside a 2D array - c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to coding and are trying to make a Connect 4 game in c#. I have a 2D array that is 6 by 6 and initialized as all 0's to begin with. When player 1 inputs their choice, the 0 in the lowest position for that column in the array is replaced with a 1. Likewise with Player 2 - with a 2 replacing the 0's (only) instead.

What I can't seem to make work is for it to check each column for 4 of the same values in a row, each row for 4 of the same values in a row, and then diagonally for 4 of the same values in a row. Below is the code I was trying to make it search along each column for 4 of the same values in a row. Could you please help. Thank you

```
x = 0;
while (x <= 5)
{
    for (row = 5; row >= 0; row--)
    {
        if (Grid[row, x] == 1)
        {
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Player1Score = 0;
        }

        if (Grid[row, x] == 2)
        {
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Player2Score = 0;
        }
    }

    x = x + 1;

    if (Player1Score == 4)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Player1 wins");
    }
    else if (Player2Score == 4)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Player2 wins");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:
Have 2 vars, player1Score, player2Score.

For rows:
go through each element in a row,

- if it is 0
- - set player1Score and player2Score to 0
- if it is 1
- - increase player1Score by 1
    -- set player2Score to 0
- if it is 2
- - increase player2Score by 1
- - set player1Score to 0

when you're done with with the row, check if any of the player scores is equal to 4, if it is, game won. Otherways reset scores and go to the another row.

You do the same thing with cols, and diagonals (in diagonals col id is equal to row id).